# A simple substitution cipher

Tags: cipher

Decode the following ciphertext:

> Eqdhwtss'l Lgxh qffgxfetr zgrqn
>   oz'l ofzkgrxeofu 'JVTKZN' lgxh
>   ygk gxk dgkt egdhxztk soztkqzt eiosrktf.
>   Vig qkt zitn aorrofu?
>   Zitn'kt pxlz ktsqwtsofu zit gsr Qshiqwtz Lgxh.
>   --Wtkns "zit Ldqkzqll Kqwwo" Rgc. 2014-05-10. "Ddd Ddd Uggr Uoddoea"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple run of [quipqiup.com](http://quipqiup.com/index.php) gives :

> Campbell's Soup announced today it's introducing 'QWERTY' soup for our more computer literate children. Who are they kidding? They're just relabeling the old Alphabet Soup. --Beryl 'the Smartass Rabbi' Dov. 2014-05-10. 'Mmm Mmm Good Gimmick'

Comment: You can probably replace ~ with Q, as in QWERTY keyboard.  Don't know how Quipqiup works but it likely tries to follow the rule of Q needing an U after it.

Comment: @gtwebb QWERTY is not in the dictionary likely, and it's equally possible for it to be Q, V, or X, thus the ~

Comment: Thanks for the info @LeppyR64.  In this case the context makes it clear that it would be Q so for a complete answer I feel for a complete answer the small amount of manual interpretation needed to replace the ~ is needed.

Comment: @gtwebb Agreed.  In this case I know that those letters are the possibility because I did it by hand ;)

Comment: You could also extrapolate from the substitution alphabet, which is `QWERTYUIOPASDFGH?KLZX?V?NM` (the layout of a QWERTY keyboard).

Comment: @gtwebb Added the Q for QWERTY. I still have a doubt about the word "Doz" right before the date. Any idea?

Comment: I believe it should be Dov based on [this](http://hellopoetry.com/words/153746/qwerty/poems/). The text with this name as the authour. βέƦẙḽ Dṏṽ the Smartass Rabbi.